# SQL table view (Visual Studio or...)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tableview

Is there any way to read .SQL document in table view in VisualStudio or any other program?

Comment: Do you mean a SQL script?  If so, that's text that you can open up in any text editor.

Comment: Like Jack Maney said, you can use any text editor for viewing SQL scripts. If you're talking about table view in SQL Server Management Studio, I don't think you can switch to table view for a plain SQL script. Table view is mainly for viewing result sets from a query, not the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

.sql quite simply contains a set of executable SQL instructions. ( [described here](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/sql) ) The instructions are in plain-text and are can be viewed with any text editor (i.e. notepad).

Based on the way your question is phrased, I assume you have instructions to create a table in SQL which you would like to view in a more user-friendly way. The best way I can think of to do this (although I am not extensively familiar with Visual Studio), is to set up a test sql environment (on localhost/a testing server - [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) comes to mind). Then open up phpmyadmin (or another database manager, although phpmyadmin is packaged with xampp) and run your code... and, if teh code is not your own, obviously look for sql injections ;) .